# Assertion error while trying to cluster multigeometry features

Tags: openlayers

I have a very big KML file (8MB | 8300+ features) and I need a way to load it offline. After some research I liked the clusterization method, using OpenLayers [`Cluster`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Cluster-Cluster.html), but it only works for points:

> Layer source to cluster vector data. Works out of the box with point geometries. For other geometry types, or if not all geometries should be considered for clustering, a custom geometryFunction can be defined.

If I try to use the method with the polygons nothing shows up. So, I tried to 'transform' the features in points while zoom is out and and show these features as a point cluster, then revert to original geometry when zoom is close enough. I found some [very similar problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246730/openlayers-4-cluster-polygons) that I relied on. But now I get an error that I didn't receive before when applying the method without converting to points:

```
AssertionError {
    code: 10, 
    name: "AssertionError", 
    message: "Assertion failed. See https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.3/doc/errors/#10 for details."
}
```

[Error code #10](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/errors/#10):

> The default geometryFunction can only handle ol/geom/Point geometries.

I found it strange to receive this error, because in the problem link I mentioned the OP does the same procedure and does not receive any error.

---

**Load layer function**

```js
// Create layer and sources
let newVectorSource = new VectorSource({})
let newVectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
    source: new Cluster({
        distance: 50,
        source: newVectorSource,
    }),
    name: layer['layer_id'],
    visible: false
});

// Read file and add to map
this.file.readAsText(path, filename).then(layer_file => {
    let format = new KML({});                                   
    newVectorSource.addFeatures(format.readFeatures(layer_file, {
        featureProjection:"EPSG:3857",
        dataProjection: "EPSG:4326"
    }));
    this.map.addLayer(newVectorLayer);

    for (let i = newVectorSource.getFeatures().length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        /* Create style function to polygons act like points, 
            so we can show them like clusters
        */

        let stroke = new Stroke({
            color: 'orange',
            width: 3
        });
        let fill = new Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.1)'
        })
    
        // Create geometry function
        let zoomInStyle = new Style({
            stroke: stroke,
            fill: fill,
            geometry: (feature) => {
                let originalFeature = newVectorSource.getFeatures()[i];
                return originalFeature.getGeometry();
            }
            
        });
        let zoomOutStyle = new Style({
            stroke: stroke,
            fill: fill,
            geometry: (feature) => {
                let type = feature.getGeometry().getType();
                if (type === 'Polygon') {
                    return feature.getGeometry().getInteriorPoint();
    
                } else if (type === 'LineString') {
                    // also tried feature.getClosestPoint();
                    return getCenter(feature.getGeometry().getExtent());
                }
            }                                   
        });
    
        let featureStyleFunction = (feature, res) => {
            if (res > 10) {
                return zoomOutStyle;                                      
            } else {
                return zoomInStyle;
            }                                   
        };
    
        // Set new style to feature
        newVectorSource.getFeatures()[i].setStyle(featureStyleFunction);                                    
    }
});
```

---

**EDIT Cache style**

```js
let styleCache = {};
let newVectorLayerCluster = new VectorLayer({
    source: new Cluster({
        distance: 100,
        source: newVectorSource,
        geometryFunction: (feature) => {
            let resolution = this.map.getView().getResolution();
            if (resolution > 10) {
                let type = feature.getGeometry().getType();
                if (type === 'Polygon') {
                    return feature.getGeometry().getInteriorPoint();

                } else if (type === 'LineString') {
                    return feature.getGeometry().getCoordinateAt(0.5);
                }
            }
        }
    }),
    style: (feature) => {
        let size = feature.get('features').length;
        let style = styleCache[size];
        if (!style) {
            style = new Style({
                image: new CircleStyle({
                    radius: 10,
                    stroke: new Stroke({
                        color: '#fff',
                    }),
                    fill: new Fill({
                        color: '#3399CC',
                    }),
                }),
                text: new Text({
                    text: size.toString(),
                    fill: new Fill({
                        color: '#fff',
                    }),
                })
            });
            styleCache[size] = style;
        }
        return style;
    },
    name: layer['layer_id'],
    visible: false
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geometryFunction the documentation and the linked question refer to is an option in the cluster source

```
source: new Cluster({
    distance: 50,
    source: newVectorSource,
    geometryFunction: function(feature) {
        let type = feature.getGeometry().getType();
        if (type === 'Polygon') {
            return feature.getGeometry().getInteriorPoint();
        } else if (type === 'LineString') {
            return feature.getGeometry().getCoordinateAt(0.5);
        }
    },
}),
```

The midpoint (label point) of a linestring may be more convenient than the extent center

Comment: Thank you, that solves the assertion problem, but the geometries are transformed into points regardless of the zoom level. If I try to implement the previously mentioned `featureStyleFunction` to `VectorLayer`, the zoom scheme works and I can see the geometry after `resolution` > 10, but the points and cluster disappear in zoom out. It would also be great if it were possible to maintain the original style of the features and not define new ones (stroke and fill). I tried to create a function to get with `feature.getStyleFunction()(feature, resolution)` but didn't work. I updated the question.

Comment: Cluster sources only work with point geometry, so you will need two layers, one with newVectorSource used directly for linestrings and polygons, and your cluster layer where the geometryFunction can return undefined for points and linestring to be excluded, Resolution is not passed to geometryFunction but you could try using map.getView(),getResolution() in the function.

Comment: I tried to reproduce a solution based on your suggestion. I created 2 layers, a simple one loading the source direct from `newVectorSource` and a layer with the cluster method. The cluster layer seems to be working perfectly, when I zoom in enough the dots disappear. However, now the original geometries are always displayed, it seems that the `featureStyleFunction` is not working correctly. Even if I change it settings, nothing happens. I updated the question with this new method, please check "EDIT 2".

Comment: If you have styles imported from a KML they are set ion the features so a layer style will not override them.  But you can use a maxResolution option on the layer to hide the layer.

Comment: This solves the problem, thank you! One last question if you don't mind, even though the problem has been solved, unfortunately the goal was not. Despite this new method of loading the features, the app continues to crash when I try to load the file with 8k + features, even if I only load the cluster layer with the distance parameter 100. I tried this solution initially because of the OL cluster example, which has a file with a similar size and number of features, in addition to being able to notice the reduction in processing when manipulating the distances. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It may be because the style function is creating a new style object each call.  If the same style is always used create a single object outside the function which the function can return, or cache styles as in the example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cluster.html

Comment: I need to apologize, because what caused the app to crash was the listing of features in another section of the app, which did not support 8300 items in the listing. However when removing this part, I can activate/deactivate the layer, but unfortunately nothing is displayed, even if I wait a while. Using the two layers I can see the features when I get close enough, but I cannot see the clusters. If I try to activate a simpler KML layer, everything works perfectly, including the clusters. I create a detailed question in GIS SE, if you want to look: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/373046/127063